# What order do I watch ALL BSG shows

Tags: battlestar-galactica

So i just finished watching Caprica, in what order do I watch the rest BSG? To include, but not limited to TV, mini series, and anything else.

Comment: Skip the original series (1978) and _Galactica 1980_. Unless you're a BIG fan of bad writing, bad acting, cheesy special effects, and late-seventies hair.

Comment: @sjl You left out mis-casting. I don't remember the acting being that bad though, it was just the lines they had to say that were terrible.

Comment: @MrLister I'm sure you're right about the acting. I have managed to repress most memories of anything specific about the show -- except the hair. "In a world ... where the Earth is only a distant memory, the last link to the home planet is _blow dryers_."

Comment: @sjl Absolutely agreed about that. No dispute! Just saying that many of the actors were simply good actors, that happened to be in the wrong place, with the wrong scripts.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. The author is asking specifically which order to watch the re-imagined BSG.

Answer (score 4):

My stock, standard answer for all "viewing order" questions - the production order. Why? Because this is the order in which the writers and creators developed the stories throughout, and even if non-serial work (like Razor) is set in the middle of previously produced episodes, you won't fully appreciate those parts until you've seen the (in-universe) later episodes which were produced first.

So, all of series 1, 2 and 3, then Razor, then all of 4, and then The Plan (definitely, absolutely, leave this to the last unless you want to spoil the entire series). If you can watch the webisodes (unfortunately, not available to Australians), then probably do that before The Plan.

I know some people think you should watch Razor chronologically - but there are a couple of spoilers.

And, as has been suggested, avoid the original series unless you like camp 80s scif-fi.